# A basic property of slowly varying functions

Tags: real-analysis, extreme-value-analysis, slowly-varying-functions

It seems that a fundamental property of a slowly varying function is that for all $\delta > 0$
$$ \lim_{x\to \infty} L(x) \, x^{-\delta} = 0.$$

How to prove this? The only book I found (that was free) stated that the proof is not difficult when using [Karamat's representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_varying_function#Karamata%27s_characterization_theorem). But I couldn't figure it out. Any help?

Comment: This is equation (2) in Karamata's paper at https://apps.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/295707.pdf . He says it it’s “well-known” and cites an earlier paper of his (http://www.numdam.org/article/BSMF_1933__61__55_0.pdf). I don’t see this property in his earlier paper, which is mostly about regularly varying functions, though the earlier paper gives and proves two properties of slowly varying functions as equations (12) and (13). [This is not an area of mathematics I have any expertise in. I just thought the question looked interesting and followed up a little.]

Comment: @SteveKass Thanks anyways, I will have a look into the papers. Much appreciated!